# Easy way to view/download javadoc/scaladocs referenced in a scala/sbt project

Tags: eclipse, scala, intellij-idea, javadoc, scaladoc

I'm a little suprised by this - I'm writing a scala play application with scalajs and while I can easily download javadocs of the dependencies by adding withJavadoc() to library dependencies in build.sbt:

1. Intellij provides hover tooltips displaying javadoc snippets, but no way (AFAICT) to browse the full javadoc (i.e. starting at index.html);
2. Scala-ide in Eclipse only provides hover/code completion (albeit, it only displays some of the documentation that Intellij provides), and doesn't have buttons at the bottom of the hover box to browse the full docs that the java editor has
3. Haven't found (yet) an sbt task that provides this - tried [sbt view task](https://github.com/nestorpersist/sbt-view) but doesn't seem usable on my multi-project build.sbt:

   ```
    [server] $ view scalajs-scripts
    Too many selected
    [1] pinfo(/home/andrew/.ivy2/cache/com.vmunier/scalajs-scripts_2.11/jars/scalajs-scripts_2.11-1.0.0.jar,/home/andrew/.ivy2/cache/com.vmunier/scalajs-scripts_2.11,1.0.0,com/vmunier,scalajs-scripts_2.11-1.0.0)
    [2] pinfo(/home/andrew/.ivy2/cache/com.vmunier/scalajs-scripts_2.11/jars/scalajs-scripts_2.11-1.0.0.jar,/home/andrew/.ivy2/cache/com.vmunier/scalajs-scripts_2.11,1.0.0,com/vmunier,scalajs-scripts_2.11-1.0.0)
    [3] pinfo(/home/andrew/.ivy2/cache/com.vmunier/scalajs-scripts_2.11/jars/scalajs-scripts_2.11-1.0.0.jar,/home/andrew/.ivy2/cache/com.vmunier/scalajs-scripts_2.11,1.0.0,com/vmunier,scalajs-scripts_2.11-1.0.0)
    [success] Total time: 0 s, completed 31-Dec-2016 17:45:01
   ```
4. Ended up writing a script to extract all javadoc jars from my ivy2 cache: [ivy2cache-doc-extract.sh](https://gist.github.com/andrewrembrandt/8036b1250060a093443f32b2fb83f7ca) but requires file open, navigation, double checking the version etc - would be handy if the IDE did this;
5. Zeal only provides the official scala api docs, and given that I'm on Fedora (25), I don't have the option of generating docsets for Dash with javadocset that OS X users have.

Is there a user friendly quick way to download browse all javadocs/scaladocs referenced in a scala project?

Perhaps by switching to maven, etc. Searching with the javadoc keyword tends to return many results around generating javadoc and is somewhat tedious to find useful results.

Thanks!

Comment: Dash does offer the functionality to download any Scala docs for libraries published with docs without having to manually publish anything. Is this not possible with Zeal?

Comment: Unfortunately Zeal lacks that - it only provides access to the stock Dash docsets - user contributed docsets aren't available either (but one can download them manually)